# How to nullify AccountId field's value in Case object

Tags: apex, servicecloud

I want to remove the value from **AccountId** field in Case Object but we can't blank the **ContactId** field value.

Could anyone help me to provide the workaround?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this auto population cannot be disabled and Triggers on Case cannot nullify the `AccountId` value, too. The only workaround I can think of is creating custom lookup field `Contact__c` and set the contact there instead of standard `ContactId` field (which you can hide from layout).